# Rounding an Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've tried using `np.round` to clean up the discrepancy between the arrays with no success, can someone please help me. it should be `np.array_equal(H,k)` is `True`

```
data_1_P = np.array([
    [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]])
data_1_Q = np.array([
    [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]])

def _hellinger_distance_py(P, Q):
    P, Q = P.tolist(), Q.tolist()
    H = []
    for p_i, q_i in zip(P, Q):
        h = 0
        for p_ij, q_ij in zip(p_i, q_i):
            d = math.sqrt(p_ij) - math.sqrt(q_ij)
            h += d**2
        H.append(math.sqrt(h))
    H = [1/math.sqrt(2) * h for h in H]
    return np.array(H)

def hellinger_distance(P, Q):
    z = np.sqrt(np.sum(abs(np.power((np.sqrt(P) - np.sqrt(Q)),2)),axis =1 ))* np.sqrt(1/ 2)
    return z

k = _hellinger_distance_py(data_1_P,data_1_Q)

array([0.        , 0.13098583, 0.11674618])

H = hellinger_distance(data_1_P,data_1_Q)

array([0.        , 0.13098583, 0.11674618])

diffs = H - k
print(diffs)
print(np.abs(diffs).sum())

[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.77555756e-17]
2.7755575615628914e-17

np.array_equal(H,k)
False

if np.abs(diffs).sum() > 0:
    print("Hellinger-Distanz:  there is discrepancy  (Different {})".format(diffs))
    code_fail()
```

Comment: I've tried to clean up because this post was a mess, but you may want to separate code and output again. Please use the review feature before posting. I would recommend to always indicate your language / runtime in the tags; I've added the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: You will never get equal arrays due to the limitations of floating points (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)). Instead of `np.array_equal` you should use `np.allclose` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose)) for floating points.